# Update one table from another within MySQL, via DBVIS SQL commander

Tags: mysql, dbvisualizer

I have adapted the solutions already posted on this question to my task but it is still generating the error:

> Unknown column `testbr.Tel` in 'field list'

```
UPDATE `Test_file_base_record_subset` `testbr`
INNER JOIN `UKTI_16sep15` `ukti`
ON `ukti.UKTI_Short_UID`=`testbr.ShortUID`
SET `testbr.Tel` = `ukti.UKTI_Tel`
WHERE `testbr.Year`=2015
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Test_file_base_record_subset` `testbr`
INNER JOIN `UKTI_16sep15` `ukti` ON `ukti`.`UKTI_Short_UID`=`testbr`.`ShortUID`
SET `testbr`.`Tel` = `ukti`.`UKTI_Tel`
WHERE `testbr`.`Year`=2015
```